# Typescript - How to use an interface in a callback function

Tags: typescript, interface, callback

Recently started using Typescript and something I'm unsure of.

I'm using an npm package `azure-storage` and specifically calling a method `doesBlobExist`:

```
blobService.doesBlobExist(containerName, blobName, (callbackResult: ErrorOrResult<BlobService.BlobResult>) => {
        //Want callbackResult.response here
});
```

That `doesBlobExist` (function coming from the npm package) looks like this:

```
doesBlobExist(container: string, blob: string, callback: ErrorOrResult<BlobService.BlobResult>): void;
```

And the type ErrorOrResult is an interface that has this:

```
interface ErrorOrResult<TResult> {
    (error: Error, result: TResult, response: ServiceResponse): void
}
```

What I'm unsure of is where I call the function, I was hoping I can use that interface and do:

`callbackResult.response` as that is in the interface however `callbackResult` keeps being returned as `null`.
On looking into it, its being set as the `error: Error` from the interface.

So is it actually possible to do what I want above, or do I have to use that function like:

```
blobService.doesBlobExist(containerName, blobName, (error, result, response) => {
        //i.e. specify the 3 items directly in the interface
});
```

Answer (score 0):

reading your problem, you can use the solution you wrote above, you can do something similar to:

```
blobService.doesBlobExist(containerName, blobName, (error, result, response) => {
        if(error !== null){
           // Do something
           return;
        } 
        // here you can work with your response data
});
```

If you want to avoid the error you can omit the if loop, and work direcly with your response, but you have to insert all the posible options in the response.

> callbackResult.response as that is in the interface however callbackResult keeps being returned as null. On looking into it, its being set as the error: Error from the interface.

As you said, you are getting a null because the function are returning no errors.